# How to create a Row of Containers without any spacing between them in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

### I am trying to create a Row of containers in flutter and I did mange to do that using a Row and Multiple containers as children. Now, the problem is that is a white space between each column. How do I remove those. I tried playing with the Cross and Main Axis alignment but it didn't help.How do I fix this so that there is no space between them at all.

[Here's a screenshot of the Row of Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2cGN.png)

---

```
Row(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  for (var i in list)
                    Container(
                      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30) /list.length,//Subtarcting 30 to adjust the padding of parent  
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
```

Comment: please show the full code. And which device or emulator you tested on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bug on Android, iOS is working fine without `border`. Consider adding a `border` with `width:0` and `color:red` as the container like this:

```
      Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 0),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30) /
                30, //Subtarcting 30 to adjust the padding of parent
          ),
      ])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the container in an Expanded widget:

```
Row(
   children: [
           for (var i in list)
              Expanded(
                 child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                         )
                   )
           ]
     )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try encapsulating `Row` widget in a `container` widget and set its color `Colors.red`

```
 Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child:Row(children:<Widget>[
  
  for (var i in list)
  Container(width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30) /5,//Subtarcting 30 to adjust the padding of parent  
                  color: Colors.red,),

]));
```

Comment: yeah I know, but will work for your requirement. You did not show your full code and the logic behind doing this.

Comment: It has no problem with iOS. Only on android the issue with pixel rendering. I am coming with a perfect solution anyway. Thanks